# Optimizing Inserting into the Middle of a List

Tags: performance, optimization, data-structures, arraylist, insertion

I have [algorithms](http://nlist.codeplex.com) that works with dynamically growing lists (contiguous memory like a C++ vector, Java ArrayList or C# List). Until recently, these algorithms would insert new values into the middle of the lists. Of course, this was usually a very slow operation. Every time an item was added, all the items after it needed to be shifted to a higher index. Do this a few times for each algorithm and things get *really* slow.

My realization was that I could add the new items to the end of the list and then rotate them into position later. That's one option!

[image: rotating items from the back]

Another option, when I know how many items I'm adding ahead of time, is to add that many items to the back, shift the existing items and then perform the algorithm in-place in the hole I've made for myself. The negative is that I have to add some default value to the end of the list and then just overwrite them.

[image: making a hole]

I did a quick analysis of these options and concluded that the second option is more efficient. My reasoning was that the rotation with the first option would result in in-place swaps (requiring a temporary). My only concern with the second option is that I am creating a bunch of default values that just get thrown away. Most of the time, these default values will be null or a mem-filled value type.

However, I'd like someone else familiar with algorithms to tell me which approach would be faster. Or, perhaps there's an even more efficient solution I haven't considered.

Comment: Love the diagrams, Mr Parks!

Comment: A diagram to demonstrate inserting elements into the middle of an indexed array is probably a bit overkill in my opinion though.  To a newbie who doesn't know what an array is, I suppose it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays aren't efficient for lots of insertions or deletions into anywhere other than the end of the array. Consider whether using a different data structure (such as one suggested in one of the other answers) may be more efficient. Without knowing the problem you're trying to solve, it's near-impossible to suggest a data structure (there's no one solution for all problems). That being said...

The second option is definitely the better option of the two. A somewhat better option (avoiding the default-value issue): simply copy `789` to the end and overwrite the middle `789` with `456`. So the only intermediate step would be `0123789789`.

Your default-value concern is, however, (generally) not a big issue:

- In Java, for one, you cannot (to my knowledge) even assign memory for an array that's not 0- or null-filled. C++ STL containers also enforce this I believe (but not C++ itself).
- The size of a pointer compared to any moderate-sized class is minimal (thus assigning it to a default value also takes minimal time) (in Java and C# everything is pointers, in C++ you can use pointers (something like `boost::shared_ptr` or a pointer-vector is preferred above straight pointers) (N/A to primitives, which are small to start, so generally not really a big issue either).

I'd also suggest forcing a reallocation to a specified size before you start inserting to the end of the array (Java's `ArrayList::ensureCapacity` or C++'s `vector::reserve`). In case you didn't know - varying-length-array implementations tend to have an internal array that's bigger than what `size()` returns or what's accessible (in order to prevent constant reallocation of memory as you insert or delete values).

Also note that there are more efficient methods to copy parts of an array than doing it manually with for loops (e.g. Java's `System.arraycopy`).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider changing your representation of the list from using a dynamic array to using some other structure.  Here are two options that allow you to implement these operations efficiently:

1. An order statistic tree is a modified type of binary tree that supports insertions and selections anywhere in O(log n) time, as well as lookups in O(log n) time.  This will increase your memory usage quite a bit because of the overhead for the pointers and extra bookkeeping, but should dramatically speed up insertions.  However, it will slow down lookups a bit.
2. If you always know the insertion point in advance, you could consider switching to a linked list instead of an array, and just keep a pointer to the linked list cell where insertions will occur.  However, this slows down random access to O(n), which could possibly be an issue in your setup.
3. Alternatively, if you always know where insertions will happen, you could consider representing your array as two stacks - one stack holding the contents of the array to the left of the insert point and one holding the (reverse) of the elements to the right of the insertion point.  This makes insertions fast, and if you have the right type of stack implementation could keep random access fast.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `TreeList` in commons collections is a usable Java implementation of an order statistics tree - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps and Linked Lists were designed for the problem you are having.  Given a indexed data structure with numbered items, the difficulty of inserting items in the middle requires a renumbering of every item in the list.

You need a data structure which is optimized to make inserts a constant `O(1)` complexity.  HashMaps were designed to make insert and delete operations lightning quick regardless of dataset size.

I can't pretend to do the HashMap subject justice by describing it.  Here is a good intro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table